# Prove that $\frac{2^{2^{2^{n+1}}}+2^{2^n}+1}{3}$ is a composite for any positive integer $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem:

*Prove that $\frac{2^{2^{2^{n+1}}}+2^{2^n}+1}{3}$ is a composite for any positive integer $n$.*

I can prove that for odd $n,$ then $2^n$ has the form $6k+2$ and $2^{2^{n+1}}$ has the form $6 \ell +4.$ Hence
$$2^{2^{2^{n+1}}}+2^{2^n}+1 =2^{6\ell +4}+2^{6k+2}+1 \equiv 2^{4}+2^2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 7,$$
and then it is easy to see that $\frac{2^{2^{2^{n+1}}}+2^{2^n}+1}{3}$ is a composite.

But, I cannot use the same way for even $n.$ My idea is to find a general form of it divisor, but I cannot find it. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sequences with this growth rate will almost always take composite values, just because of the fact that primes are increasingly rare. If you don't have a good reason to suspect this problem to be "easily" solvable (e.g. this is from an assignment), it might as well be as hard as finding Fermat primes.

Comment: Related to the previous comment — the fact that you're looking at values of the form you have suggests that primes of the form $2^a+2^b+1$ and/or Fermat primes are worth a look. 7 is both, $2^3-1$ and $3\cdot2+1=2+2^2+1$; the next Fermat prime is $31$, which is where I'd start. Alternately, looking at 13 as it's $3\cdot 2^2+1$ might be worth study.

Comment: Sorry, thinko — where I said 'Fermat' above I meant 'Mersenne', of course. But Mersenne primes are going to be no help beyond $p=7$, because a number of the form $2^a+2^b+1$ can never be 0 mod any larger Mersenne prime. ($2^a$ and $2^b$ will each always be of the form $2^i\bmod 2^n-1$ for some $i\lt n$ and so essentially by uniqueness of binary expansion the sum $2^a+2^b+1$ can never be $2^n-1$.)

Comment: Okay, more digging on this: the first instance for even $n$ is $2^{256}+2^4+1$. This _is_ composite, but the factors are 3 (of course), 2549, 1762903, and then a 67-digit probable prime. The binary expansion of 1762903 doesn't look to have anything useful in it, but 2549 can be written as $5\cdot(2^9+1)-2^4$. I suspect that finding small factors of the next case could provide a possible pattern, but given that it involves $2^{32}$ squarings, that's likely to take a chunk of compute time even to do the small-divisor tests.

Comment: Also possibly of note, $3\cdot 2549$ can be written as $2^{13}-2^9-2^5-1$. This somewhat suggests looking at $2^{3\cdot 2^n+1}-2^{2\cdot 2^n+1}-2^{2^n+1}-1$ as a possible divisor of $2^{2^{2^{n+1}}}+2^{2^n}+1$...

Comment: Our only hope is algebraic or aufeurillian factors or similar stuff. For $\ n=10\ $, I could not find a factor yet.

Comment: According to my calculations , for $\ n=10\ $, there is no factor below $\ 4\cdot 10^{10}\ $